# Quick data loading using webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

Developing quiz application, displaying Questions with option.

The questions are in database in *HTML format*. Using WebView I am displaying a Q&A.

When I use a TextView, the Q&A display themselves neatly. But when I use a WebView to display Q&A, it takes a long time to display the question and at the same time it is *displaying the options repeatedly*.

My Code:

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList;
static ArrayList<String> optionlist;

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.question);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadData(listItem.getquestion(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(14);
webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
    optionlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    optionlist = stringList.get(i);

    RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(this.getContext());

    newRadioButton.setText(optionlist.get(2));
    newRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton, layoutParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you add anything to the WebView (once or repeatedly), but here are some pointers to make the code you included run faster:

- use a for-each loop, they are faster and easier.
- remove the new ArrayList declaration because in the next line you just overwrite it with an existing ArrayList

Like this:

```
for (ArrayList<String> currentList : stringList) {
    RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(this.getContext());
    newRadioButton.setText(currentList.get(2));
    newRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton, layoutParams);
}
```